# Python script doesn't work when passing in a argument from a text file

Tags: python, sql, json, python-3.x

I have a python script that is supposed to loop through a text file and gather the domain as an argument from each line in the text file. Then it is supposed to use the domain as an argument in a SQL query. The issue is when I'm passing in the domain as an argument the JSON output the script produces is blank. If I set the domain_name argument in my sql query directly inside the query then the script outputs perfect JSON format. As you can see in the top of my script right below def connect_to_db() I start to loop through the text file. I'm not sure where in my code the error is occurring by any assistance would be greatly appreciated!

**Code**

```
from __future__ import print_function

try:
    import psycopg2
except ImportError:
    raise ImportError('\n\033[33mpsycopg2 library missing. pip install psycopg2\033[1;m\n')
    sys.exit(1)

import re
import sys
import json
import pprint

DB_HOST = 'crt.sh'
DB_NAME = 'certwatch'
DB_USER = 'guest'


def connect_to_db():
    filepath = 'test.txt'
    with open(filepath) as fp:
        for cnt, domain_name in enumerate(fp):
            print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, domain_name))
            print(domain_name)
            domain_name = domain_name.rstrip()

            conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname={0} user={1} host={2}".format(DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_HOST))
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            cursor.execute(
                "SELECT c.id, x509_commonName(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate) FROM certificate c, certificate_identity ci WHERE c.id = ci.certificate_id AND ci.name_type = 'dNSName' AND lower(ci.name_value) = lower('**domain_name**') AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timestamp();")

            unique_domains = cursor.fetchall()

        # print out the records using pretty print
        # note that the NAMES of the columns are not shown, instead just indexes.
        # for most people this isn't very useful so we'll show you how to return
        # columns as a dictionary (hash) in the next example.
            pprint.pprint(unique_domains)

            outfilepath = domain_name + ".json"
            with open(outfilepath, 'a') as outfile:
                    outfile.write(json.dumps(unique_domains, sort_keys=True, indent=4))

if __name__ == "__main__":
#    filepath = 'test.txt'
#    with open(filepath) as fp:
#        for cnt, domain_name in enumerate(fp):
#            print("Line {}: {}".format(cnt, domain_name))
#            print(domain_name)
#            domain_name = domain_name.rstrip()
    connect_to_db()
```

Comment: What's the error? Why do you connect to the db for each line? Do you mean `"SELECT c.id, x509_commonName(c.certificate), x509_issuerName(c.certificate) FROM certificate c, certificate_identity ci WHERE c.id = ci.certificate_id AND ci.name_type = 'dNSName' AND lower(ci.name_value) = lower('%s') AND x509_notAfter(c.certificate) > statement_timestamp();".format(domain_name)`?

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks for your reply! I tried the new sql query and it unfortunately gives me a timeout error. If I replace **domain_name** with google.com then I get an error NameError: global name 'google' is not defined. Do you have any idea of what the issue could be? I would greatly appreciate your help!

Comment: `domain_name` is a variable that you defined earlier in the code (`for cnt, domain_name in enumerate(fp):`). You didn't define `google`, there is no such variable, you want the text, so it's `"google"`.

Comment: @CristiFati Thank you for your reply! I replaced google.com with "google.com" and now the script runs but the output it produces to the JSON files are blank. Do you have any idea of the issue?

Comment: This is strictly related to your data in the database. You should take a look at the tables involved in your query and check their contents. Also you might want to try `"google.com"` as domain, or modify the query to use the `LIKE` operator when comparing to domain names (and maybe other fields too).

Comment: @CristiFati Thanks again for your reply! I tried 'google.com' and "google.com" and they both don't work. Do you know any alternative to using the LIKE statement since I would prefer not to use LIKE due to the performance impacts.

Comment: I am not a *DB* expert/fan. You got past that problem, from now on it's just debugging and checking your data, and both of those are in your yard.